# Trying to make a simple Recipe Program

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm trying to build a recipe program that asks people for info about a recipe and stores it. 
The menu is in a case statement that just runs and they push whatever number for the thing they're trying to access. However whenever I push any buttons it just skips what's in that option and goes back to the menu. I tried debugging but it seems like it recognizes the input and then goes back to menu anyway. Here's the class and the first method it tries to access (but won't)

```
package potluck;
import java.util.*;

import potluck.*;

public class Controller {
    private Scanner input;
    private Member member;
    private AdminMember admin;

    private final static int USER_LOGIN = 0;
    private final static int CREATE_MEMBER = 1;
    private final static int CREATE_ADMIN = 2;
    private final static int CREATE_RECIPE = 3;
    private final static int COMMENT = 4;
    private final static int DELETE_RECIPE = 5;
    private final static int EXIT = 8;

    public Controller(){
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        startUp();//no better name to be thought of
    }

    public void startUp() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int choice;
        do {
            this.displayMenu();
            choice = input.nextInt();
            input.nextLine();// clears carriage return
            //depending on choice takes to a different menu
            switch (choice) {
//              case USER_LOGIN:
//                  member.enterPassword();
//                  break;
        case CREATE_MEMBER: 
            new Member();
            break;
        case CREATE_ADMIN: 
            Member.addAdmin();
            break;
        case CREATE_RECIPE:
            Recipe.addRecipe();
            break;
        case COMMENT:
            Recipe.addComment();
            break;
        case DELETE_RECIPE:
            Recipe.deleteRecipe();
            break;
        case EXIT:
            System.out.println("Thanks for using our software");
            System.exit(choice);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Error, Invalid selection.");
        }
    } while (choice != 8); //choice 8 exits
}
private void displayMenu() {
    System.out.println("1 Create Member");
    System.out.println("2 Create Admin Member");
    System.out.println("3 Create Recipe");
    System.out.println("4 Leave Comment");
    System.out.println("5 Delete Recipe");
    System.out.println("8 Exit");
    System.out.println("Please enter menu option, to exit enter 8");
    }
}
```

here's the member class it tries to access.
    package potluck;
     import java.util.Scanner;
     public class Member {

```
 private int memberID = 0;
 private String name;
 private String alias;
 private String email;
 private String username;
 private String password;
 private Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

public void Member(){ //constructor
    memberID =+ 1;
    name = "";
    alias = "";
    email = "";
    username = "";
    password = "";

    setName();
    setAlias();
    setEmail();
    setUsername();
    setPassword();
    System.out.println("Member Created");
   }

  public  void addMember() {
     new Member();
  }
```

So just as a recap. I'm only trying to get the CREATE_MEMBER option to work at the moment. whatever is wrong with it, is probably also wrong with the rest.

Comment: You're doing nothing with the member. It's destroyed as soon as it is created. In fact, `public void Member()` is not a constructor. Constructors have no return type. This should probably be `public Member()` You're using an implicit constructor that doesn't exist in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not assigning your `Member` to your variable:

```
member = new Member();
```

Also note that what you call a constructor is not in fact one. You need to remove the `void` for it to be one:

```
public Member() { //constructor
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You use the `Member` class like with calling its `static` methods. You have to call the constructor and create the instance of your class.

```
Member member = new Member();
```

The constructor of any class doesn't require the return type, so delete the `void` word.

```
public Member() {
   ...
}
```

If you want to add `1` to your memberID as the **global** variable that belongs to **all* instances, you have to define that variable as `static`. So:

```
private static int memberID = 0;
```

And finally your `addmember(..)` method does nothing. If you want to initialize the instance variables within the created instance `Member member = new Member();`, you have to amend your constructor or create plenty of setters.

```
public class Member {

   // constructor
   public Member(String name, String alias ...) {
      this.name = name;
      this.alias = alias;

      ...

   }

   // setters
   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public void setAlias(String alias) {
      this.alias = alias;
   }

...

}
```